# Manually delete project in Weblate

Tags: weblate

I did some very unspeakable things with my weblate installation in order to change the git-branch the translation files can be found on.

Weblate hated my attempts and now continues to give all kinda errors.
As final resort I would just love to delete the project and recreate it.

Only: the "Delete project" gives me a "500 Internal Server Error".
The project and its components aren't removed. 
Trying to remove the components give a similar error.

Does anyone know how to clean up and remove a project by hand? Even if there are 50 steps or more, a solution is all I care about.

PS: The other projects on the server are still fully functional and should remain so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always do the removal from the Django management shell:

```
$ ./manage.py shell
Python 2.7.13 (default, Jan 19 2017, 14:48:08) 
[GCC 6.3.0 20170118] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> from weblate.trans.models import Project
>>> project = Project.objects.get(slug='hello')
>>> project.delete()
```

But the deletion from admin interface should not be that slow on current versions, if you're up to date, please [file issue on that](https://github.com/WeblateOrg/weblate/issues/new).

Comment: The project.delete() function took 8h to complete. Guess an update is not a luxury. Everything is clean again now, so updating will be a breeze. I hope :-)

Comment: Update will most likely solve this as well. We used to do database cleanup on every unit deletion what made mass deletion really slow.